# Re-entry permit to Japan with a work visa?

Tags: japan, working-visas

I recently received a working visa in Japan. However, I am planning to leave for South Korea for a short trip. I recall hearing something about needing a re-entry permit? Judging from [this page](http://www.juridique.jp/visa2.html#reentry) it would seem it is not necessary, but I just want to double check with the community in case I'm missing something.

Is it necessary for me to have a re-entry permit into Japan while holding a work visa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer necessary to obtain a re-entry permit if you are leaving Japan for up to one year and don't fall under a number of special cases which are not usually relevant for an ordinary person. Just be careful to tick the correct box on the departure form at the airport. More information [here](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/newimmiact_1/en/point_3-4.html) (see also [here](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/re-ed/EDcard_leaf_en.pdf) for the latest version of the departure form).

Comment: The card example on your link is a little outdated.  See https://japaninfoswap.com/embarkation-and-disembarkation-card-card-changes-at-airports-in-japan/ for the latest one.  It's a great improvement, because when filling out the old card I always had to pause and remember that while "special permanent resident" implies an extraordinary situation of permanent residency, "special re-entry permission" implied an ordinary departure.

Comment: @fkraiem Ahh the small print. My apologies, I shall remove my previous comment.